# Coniditional formatting of groups in same column based on variables

Tags: excel, vba

i have this Table:

[image]

and i need to format the column named "cumulative" based on a row that contains a match formula which gives the following results: 4, 10, 17, 24

so as you can see i have highlighted the groups 1-4 and 5-10 and 11-17 and 18-24 manually, but i need to automate this process if possible.
so when any variable is changed the formatting is changed as well.

Comment: Are you trying to format the cells in column "Cumulative" based on the values in column "Unit"?

Comment: yes but the threshold of each group is variable so the first group is not always 1-4 it might be 1-6, the 4 or the 6 could be found in another [row](http://1drv.ms/1og9Nxs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your question it seems as that your variable that you are wanting to group by is in another cell but jsut isn't displayed in your example above.  If that is the case then under conditional formatting you can go to create a new rule and Use a formulato determine which cells to format from there you can use the numbers that are in your variable cells to color code your column.

So for instance if your variable is in cell A1, in the conditional formatting formula you could have it format that cell for anything that is equal to or less than A1.  You could use the format cells based on values but it only goes to a 3 color code and it appears that youa re wanting to go further than just three colors from your example.  You would have to create a rule for each of your formatting variables so if you want to have 5 different colors, then you would need five different rules.  Also if you are going to use a less than or equal too, remember to check the box on the right hand side of the rules manager that says stop if true, that way the formatting isnt trying to utilize all the rules

Comment: Good answer, I would add, select the cells you want to format and enter a conditional formula such as this `=AND(B2>0,B2<=4)`. Change 0 and 4 to cell references to make the range dynamic.

Comment: thanks alot, i tried the And formula but what i was missing is the "stop if true" !! ^^